# Converting strings into another data type, Python

Tags: python, string, types, tuples

I have the string `"(0, 0, 0)"`. I'd like to be able to convert this to a tuple. The built in `tuple` function doesn't work for my purposes because it treats each character as an individual item. I want to be able to convert `"(0, 0, 0)"` to `(0, 0, 0)` programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('(0,0,0)')
(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Or `eval(string, {}, {})` in pre-2.6, where `ast` doesn't exist

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Also David Zaslavsky, in my case it's 2.7.2 so that doesn't matter. Good information, nonetheless.